# can not read from pipe with execlp

Tags: c++, linux, bash, pipe, exec

For an assignment, i am supposed to implement the linux terminal. My terminal should support arguments with pipes. Like the user can input:
`ls | grep ".cpp"`
What i have done so far is:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid==0)
{
  close(fd[0]);
  dup2(fd[1],1);
  close(fd[1]);
  execlp("/bin/ls","ls");
}
wait(NULL);
pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{
  close(fd[1]);
  dup2(fd[0],0);
  close(fd[0]);
  execlp("/bin/grep","grep",".cpp");
}
```

my first child works perfectly, writes the output of ls into a pipe declared earlier, however, my second child runs grep, but it apparently can not get input from pipe. Why is that so?
when i run it, my output is
    /root/OS $ ls | grep

it just gets stuck like this

Answer (score 2):

Don't ignore compiler warnings:

```
$ gcc lol.c
lol.c: In function ‘main’:
lol.c:14:5: warning: not enough variable arguments to fit a sentinel [-Wformat=]
     execlp("/bin/ls","ls");
     ^
lol.c:23:5: warning: missing sentinel in function call [-Wformat=]
     execlp("/bin/grep","grep",".cpp");
     ^
```

Here's `man execlp`:

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.  The list of arguments **must** be terminated by a NULL
>          pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Always compile with `-Werror` so that compilation fails if there are warnings, and preferably also with `-Wall` to get warnings for all potential issues.

Here's your program with a main method and sentinels added:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main() {
  int fd[2];
  int pid;

  pipe(fd);
  pid = fork();
  if(pid==0)
  { 
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1],1);
    close(fd[1]);
    execlp("/bin/ls","ls", NULL);
  }
  wait(NULL);
  pid=fork();
  if(pid==0)
  { 
    close(fd[1]);
    dup2(fd[0],0);
    close(fd[0]);
    execlp("/bin/grep","grep",".cpp", NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here's how it runs now:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror lol.c -o lol
$ ./lol
foo.cpp
```

Comment: I think you should add that the call to `wait()` was misplaced by the OP.  The way it is, if the directory has too many entries, `ls` will stop while writing to a pipe from which no one is consuming data.  The consumer process should be started as soon as possible, and the main process should wait for both after the whole pipeline has been properly set,